# Estou com uma dúvida em relação a instalação e configuração do composer (PHPUnit)

Tags: php

Estou realizando um projeto no Instituto Federal do Triângulo Mineiro, sobre um sistema de controle de alunos feito em php, portanto, estou começando uma fase de testes utilizando o PHPUnit e tenho minhas dúvidas porque não sou experiente com essa ferramenta. Não estou conseguindo instalar e configurar o composer pra executar esses testes, teria como alguém me dar alguma dica?  O Sistema está no github. segue o link > https://github.com/Leonardo-Souza/aanc

Obs: Já instalei e configurei o PHPUnit o problema está somente nesta parte do composer.

Se alguém tiver uma dica que facilite essa instalação e configuração eu agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Tudo o que você precisa é criar um arquivo chamado `composer.json` na pasta raiz do seu projeto. O conteúdo do arquivo será o seguinte:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

(PS: isso significa que a última versão da dependência `phpunit/phpunit` será instalada quando instalarmos as dependências de desenvolvimento do projeto).

Então, com o Composer já instalado, rode:

```
composer install
```

Quando o comando finalizar, o PHPUnit estará instalado na pasta `vendor/phpunit`. Para rodá-lo, basta simplesmente executar:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: obrigado, o problema já foi resolvido ! :D